# Why we can't use (values) like this?

Tags: racket

```
(define (avg . l)
  (/ (apply + l) (length l)))

(define (delist ls)
  (apply values ls))

(avg (delist '(1 2 3))) ;;error
(avg 1 2 3) ;; return 2
```

without call-with-values, can I bind the value returned by values to each parameter in other ways?

Comment: `(define-values (a b c) (delist '(1 2 3))`
`(avg a b c)`

Comment: That's an ideal case for `call-with-values`, though.

Comment: `(let-values (((a b c) (delist '(1 2 3)))) (avg a b c))`

Comment: Why are you jumping through hoops with `values` when `(apply avg '(1 2 3))` does what you seem to want?

Answer (score 0):

> can I bind the value returned by values to each parameter in other ways?

Here are most of the ways I know of to bind variables to returned values in Racket:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(define (list->values lst) (apply values lst))

(define-values (a b c) (list->values '(1 2 3)))
(displayln (+ a b c))

(let-values ([(d e f) (list->values '(4 5 6))])
  (displayln (+ d e f)))

(require racket/match)
(match/values (list->values '(7 8 9))
              ([x y z] (displayln (+ x y z))))

(require srfi/8)
(receive (i j k) (list->values '(10 11 12)) (displayln (+ i j k)))

(displayln (call-with-values (lambda () (list->values '(13 14 15))) +))
```